# deviate the response from provider to relying party incase of using openid

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

i am trying to redirect the response which is sent by the provider to the consumer incase of openid perspective. in this the authentication process that is done at the website like google or yahoo, should not be visible to user. the user thinks that the authentication process done internally

let me know the procedure to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Isnt that the point though - the user is using their google etc credentials to login, so shouldnt it be visible to the user...